# How to use "problem detail" responses for unhandled exceptions?

Tags: c#, exception, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.2

As [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/release-notes/aspnetcore-2.2?view=aspnetcore-2.2#problem-details-support), `ProblemDetails` (based on the RFC 7807 specification) is the standard response for client error codes in ASP.NET Core 2.2. This works fine when I return things like `NotFound()` in my API controller action methods.

But how do I configure my Web API project to also use `ProblemDetails` for unhandled exceptions ("500 Internal Server Error" responses)? By default such unhandled exceptions either return a HTML body (when `UseDeveloperExceptionPage()` or `UseExceptionHandler(somePath)` was called) or no body (if neither method was called).

My preferred solution would always return a `ProblemDetails` object when an exception happens in API controllers, but still return HTML pages for exceptions on other (view related) controllers. In development mode the `ProblemDetails` object should have full exception details, in production only very limited details. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `ProblemDetails` does not support for `404` and `500` exception.A workaround is to install the `Hellang.Middleware.ProblemDetails` package`,

```
Install-Package Hellang.Middleware.ProblemDetails
```

And then configure in startup.cs, set `IncludeExceptionDetails` to `true` under development environment only.

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        CurrentEnvironment = env;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    public IHostingEnvironment CurrentEnvironment { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddProblemDetails(setup=> {
          
            setup.IncludeExceptionDetails = _ => CurrentEnvironment.IsDevelopment();
        });
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {           
        app.UseProblemDetails();           
        //...
    }
}
```

Refer to [here](https://jasonrowe.com/2019/01/04/asp-net-core-problem-details-examples/).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. For future reference, this GitHub issue requests that to be fixed in ASP.NET Core itself: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/4953

Comment: Works great, thanks. Just two comments: 1) `IncludeExceptionDetails` already behaves that way by default, see [ProblemDetailsOptionsSetup.cs](https://github.com/khellang/Middleware/blob/master/src/ProblemDetails/ProblemDetailsOptionsSetup.cs). 2) The different configurations for UI and API calls can be done with something like shown [in this sample](https://github.com/christianacca/ProblemDetailsDemo/blob/master/src/ProblemDetailsDemo.Api/Startup.cs).

Comment: @cremor Perfect.Thank you.