# How can I hide System.Exception errors on .NET Core?

Tags: .net-core, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi

I try to improve myself with .NET Web API now and I am trying to return a custom error in Swagger. But when returning this custom error, I can see the error is on which line. How can I do to prevent this?

```
public async Task<BookCreateDTO> CreateBook(BookCreateDTO bookCreateDto)
        {
            if (await _context.Books.AnyAsync(x => x.Name == bookCreateDto.Name))
            {
                throw new BookExistException("Book already exist");
            }

            var book= _mapper.Map<Book>(bookCreateDto);
            _context.Books.Add(book);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return book;
        }
```

What should I do to see only this exception message in the Swagger response?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: **Exceptions should be exceptional**: Don't throw exceptions for non-exceptional errors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Exceptions should be exceptional**: Don't throw exceptions for non-exceptional errors.

I don't recommend specifying your web-service's response DTO type in the C# action method return type because it limits your expressiveness (as you're discovering).

- Instead use `IActionResult` or `ActionResult<T>` to document the default (i.e. HTTP 2xx) response type and then list error DTO types in `[ProducesResponseType]` attributes with their corresponding HTTP status codes.

  - This also means that each response status code should only be associated with a *single* DTO type.
  - While Swagger is not expressive enough to allow you to say "if the response status is HTTP 200 then the response body/DTO is **one-of** `DtoFoo`, `DtoBar`, `DtoQux`", in-practice a well-designed web-service API *should not* exhibit that kind of response DTO polymorphism.

    - And if it didn't, how else is a client supposed to know what the type is just from the HTTP headers? (Well, you could put the full DTO type-name in a custom HTTP response header, but that introduces other problems...)
- For error conditions, add the errors to `ModelState` (with the `Key`, if possible) and [let ASP.NET Core handle the rest for you](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-6.0#validation-failure-error-response) with [`ProblemDetails`](https://code-maze.com/using-the-problemdetails-class-in-asp-net-core-web-api/).
- If you do throw an exception, then ASP.NET Core [can be configured to automatically render it as a `ProblemDetails`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55298800/how-to-use-problem-detail-responses-for-unhandled-exceptions) - or it can show the `DeveloperExceptionPage` - or something else entirely.

  - I note that a good reason to *not* throw an exception inside a Controller for non-exceptional exceptions is because your logging framework may choose to log more details about unhandled exceptions in ASP.NET Core's pipeline, which would result in useless extraneous entries in your logs that make it harder to find "*real*" exceptions that you need to fix.
- Document the DTOs used, and their corresponding HTTP status codes, with `[ProducesResponseType]`: this is very useful when using Swagger/NSwag to generate online documentation and client libraries.
- Also: **do not use EF entity types as DTOs or ViewModels**.

  - **Reason 1**: When the response (with EF entity objects) is serialized, entities with lazy-loaded properties will cause your entire database object-graph to be serialized (because the JSON serializer will traverse every property of every object).
  - **Reason 2**: Security! If you directly accept an EF entity as an input request body DTO or HTML form model then users/visitors can set properties arbitrarily, e.g. `POST /users` with `{ accessLevel: 'superAdmin' }`, for example. While you can exclude or restrict which properties of an object can be set by a request it just adds to your project's maintenance workload (as it's another non-local, manually-written, list or definition in your program you need to ensure is kept in-sync with *everything else*.
  - **Reason 3**: Self-documenting intent: an entity-type is for in-proc state, not as a communications contract.
  - **Reason 4**: the members of an entity-type are never *exactly* what you'll want to expose in a DTO.

    - For example, your `User` entity will have a `Byte[] PasswordHash`  and `Byte[] PasswordSalt` properties <sub>(I hope...)</sub>, and obviously those two properties must **never** be exposed; but in a User DTO for editing a user you might want *different* members, like `NewPassword` and `ConfirmPassword` - which don't map to DB columns at all.
  - **Reason 5**: On a related note to Reason 4, using Entity classes as DTOs automatically binds the exact design of your web-service API to your database model.

    - Supposing that one day you *absolutely* need to make changes to your database design: perhaps someone told you the business requirements changed; that's normal and happens *all the time*.
    - Supposing the DB design change was from allowing only 1 address per customer (because the street addresses were being stored in the same table as customers) to allowing customers to have many addresses (i.e. the street-address columns are moved to a different table)...
    - ...so you make the DB changes, run the migration script, and deploy to production - but suddenly all of your web-service clients stop working because they all assumed your `Customer` object had inline Street address fields but now they're missing (because your `Customer` EF entity types' don't have street-address columns anymore, that's over in the `CustomerAddress` entity class).
    - If you had been using a dedicated DTO type specifically for `Customer` objects then during the process of updating the design of the application you would have noticed builds breaking sooner (rather than inevitably later!) due to C# compile-time type-checking in your DTO-to-Entity (and Entity-to-DTO) mapping code - that's a benefit right there.
    - But the main benefit is that it allows you to completely abstract-away your underlying database design - and so, in our example, if you have remote clients that depend on Customer address information being inline then your Customer DTO can still emulate the older design by inlining the *first* Customer Address into the original Customer DTO when it renders its JSON/XML/Protobuf response to the remote client. That saves time, trouble, effort, money, stress, complaints, firings, unnecessary beatings, grievous bodily harm and a scheduled dental hygienist's appointment.

---

Anyway, I've modified your posted code to follow the guidance above:

- I added `[ProducesResponseType]` attributes.

  - I appreciate it is redundant to specify the default response type  `BookCreateDTO` twice (in `[ProducesResponseType]` as well as `ActionResult<BookCreateDTO>` - you should be able to remove either one of those without affecting Swagger output.
- I added an explicit `[FromBody]`, just to be safe.
- If the "book-name is unused" check fails, it returns the model validation message in ASP.NET's stock `BadRequest` response, which is rendered as an IETF RFC 7807 response, *aka* `ProblemDetails` **instead** of throwing an exception and then hoping that you configured your ASP.NET Core pipeline (in `Configure()`) to handle it as a `ProblemDetails` instead of, say, invoking a debugger or using `DeveloperExceptionPage`.

  - Note that in the case of a name conflict we want to return HTTP 409 Conflict and not HTTP 400 Bad Request, so the `conflictResult.StatusCode = 409;` is overwritten.
- The final response is generated from a new `BookCreateDTO` instance via AutoMapper and `Ok()` instead of serializing your `Book` entity object.

```
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(BookCreateDTO), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(ProblemDetails), StatusCodes.Status409Conflict)]
public async Task< ActionResult<BookCreateDTO> > CreateBook( [FromBody] BookCreateDTO bookCreateDto )
{
    // Does a book with the same name exist? If so, then return HTTP 409 Conflict.
    if( await _context.Books.AnyAsync(x => x.Name == bookCreateDto.Name) )
    {
        this.ModelState.Add( nameof(BookCreateDTO.Name), "Book already exists" );
        BadRequestObjectResult conflictResult = this.BadRequest( this.ModelState );
        // `BadRequestObjectResult` is HTTP 400 by default, change it to HTTP 409:
        conflictResult.StatusCode = 409;
        return conflictResult;
    }

    Book addedBook;
    {
        addedBook = this.mapper.Map<Book>( bookCreateDto );
        _ = this.context.Books.Add( book );
        _ = await this.context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    BookCreateDTO responseDto = this.mapper.Map<BookCreateDTO >( addedBook );

    return this.Ok( responseDto );
}
```