# ID not being passed from a Form view to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to implement an edit form where saved details can be edited, but it is not working. The ID is not being passed to the controller from the view when the "save" button is clicked and I am not sure why it returns Id = 0, but when the back button is clicked it does pass the id. I cannot figure out what

My Model class

```
public class Organisations
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Organisation_name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Industry { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

}

My Controller

```
//Get action method
     public async Task<IActionResult> OrgEdit(int? id)
        {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var orgs = await _context.Organisations.FindAsync(id);
        if (orgs == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }


         ViewBag.orgId = id;
            return View(orgs);
        }

//Post action method
        [HttpPost, ActionName("OrgEdit")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> OrgEdit(int orgId)
        {
        if (orgId == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        var orgToUpdate = await _context.Organisations.FirstOrDefaultAsync(s => s.ID == orgId);
        if (await TryUpdateModelAsync<Organisations>(
            orgToUpdate,
            "",
             s => s.Organisation_name, s => s.Industry, s => s.Email, s => s.Password))
        {
            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(OrgHome));
            }
            catch (DbUpdateException /* ex */)
            {
                //Log the error (uncomment ex variable name and write a log.)
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. " +
                    "Try again, and if the problem persists, " +
                    "see your system administrator.");
            }
        }
        ViewBag.orgId = orgId;
        return View(orgToUpdate);
    }
```

My View

```
  @model VolunteerMngSystm.Models.Organisations

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_OrgLayout.cshtml";
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit";
}

<h1>Edit</h1>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-controller="Users" asp-action="OrgEdit">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="ID" />

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Organisation_name" style="font-weight: bold;" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Organisation_name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Organisation_name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Industry" style="font-weight: bold;" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Industry" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Industry" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Email" style="font-weight: bold;" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Password" style="font-weight: bold;" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Password" type="password" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div><br /><br />
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-dark" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<a asp-action="OrgHome" asp-route-orgId="@ViewBag.orgId">Back</a>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

I hope that someone can help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Rename the parameter in the POST to "ID" not "orgID"

Comment: You should not be using EF entity types as view-models ([see my reasons here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70103697/159145)). You need to define a separate class. To have ASP.NET Core perform model-binding you use `[FromForm]` on a parameter of your `[HttpPost]` action method.

Comment: This should be closed by typo

Comment: @Steve It worked thanks, but I just don't understand why that worked as I have done the same thing for a different model and the id had the name usrId but it didn't cause any problems?

Comment: Difficult to say, perhaps in the other page the _usrId_ was inside the form block.